# How to make new array or arrays with contents from other arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, sorting

First array:

```
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];
```

Second array:

```
const arr2 = [['some1', 'some2'], ['some3', 'some4']];
```

Desired array:

```
const finalArr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['some1', 'some2'], ['some3', 'some4']];
```

So, basically `finalArr` should have first index array of `arr1` and the `rest` of `arr2`.

How can this be done?

Comment: `const finalArr = [arr1[0], ...arr2]` this should to the trick.

Comment: I can just talk for myself, and for me the reason was that the question lacks - what was already tried and what didn't work.

Comment: You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not care about destroying `arr2`, neither about having a deep copy of `arr1[0]`, a simple `unshift()` can do that:

```js
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];
const arr2 = [['some1', 'some2'], ['some3', 'some4']];

arr2.unshift(arr1[0]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

Of course those are really some conditions which may not fit your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use ES6 spread operator as below.

```
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];

const arr2 = [['some1', 'some2'], ['some3', 'some4']];

const finalArr = [arr1[0], ...arr2];

console.log(finalArr);
```

Or use concat function.

```
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];
const arr2 = [['some1', 'some2'], ['some3', 'some4']];
const finalArr = [arr1[0]].concat(arr2);

console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];

const arr2 = [['some1', 'some2'], ['some3', 'some4']];
cont finalArr = Array();
finalArr.push(arr1[0]);
finalArr.push(arr2[0]);
finalArr.push(arr2[1]);
```

You can also iterate through the arrays and push them dynamically.